# Interactive clock plot in R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, interactive, plotly

I'm looking for an interactive version of a clock plot. Similar plots are also called polar plots.

This is a static [example](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/49-clock-plot/) of what I need (created in R):

[image]

[Polar chart plot](https://plot.ly/r/polar-chart/) in `plotly` is also pretty close:
[image]

Does anyone know where can I find an example of an interactive clock plot? Or how to create it from scratch.

Comment: ggplot2 + polar_coord()? Dunno about interactive.

Comment: thanks but the whole point is about it being interactive

Comment: It's been along time, but did you ever find a solution in R for this question?

Comment: @kputschko not at the time when I looked for it. I haven't looked for a solution since then.